# Counting items using ngFor with pipes -angular 2

Tags: angular, ngfor

I am basically trying to count then number of list outlined by the ngFor directive. I have followed quite a number of solutions to resolve my issue but it is not a success. Below is my code and i get the error, parent is not defined.

**pipe**

```
@Pipe({name: 'keys'})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {


    parent : string;
    transform(value) : any {
        let keys = [];



        if(value) {

            this.parent = value;

            return Object.keys(value)
 }
    }
}
```

**html**

```
<div *ngFor="let game of games">

  <div *ngFor="let key of game| keys">

  <li> {{game[key].type}} </li>

  {{ game[key].location}}

    Count: {{game.parent.length}}

</div>


</div>
```

**output**

```
 mario - germany
 kart - london
 rings - france 

total number of items  = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `index` of ngFor instead of a custom pipe

```
<div *ngFor="let game of games">

  <div *ngFor="let key of game| i=index ">

  <li> {{game[i].type}} </li>

  {{ game[i].location}}

    Count: {{game.parent.length}}

</div>
```

Comment: i want the total number of items displayed.  not listing the numbers beside the items

Comment: can you give a example json and expected output. `total number of items displayed can be calculated using games.length*..` itself

Comment: please look at the edited question now and look at the output

Comment: @XamarinDevil is your issue fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Your count should be outside the div,

```
<div *ngFor="let game of games">
  <div *ngFor="let key of game| i=index ">
  <li> {{game[i].type}} </li>
  {{ game[i].location}}   
</div>
<div>
 total number of items: {{game.parent.length}}
</div>
```

Comment: this is throwing an error `Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined `

Comment: besides, i really need to use the keys to display the data

Comment: where are you using toUpperCase?

Comment: i am not using toUpperCase but that error was caused by i = index

Comment: why suddenly you are  this error? it used to work right?

Comment: the i = index doesn't work with the code because i am using keys .. i guess. but my code is able to display the list without the i = index

Comment: try without index, inorder to get the count you just have to use length

Comment: {{game.length}} is what i used but nothing appears.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141603/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-beginner).